# What kind of bike should I rent?

Tags: mountain-bike

I'm just looking to rent for a weekend away. I really know nothing about bikes and could use a hand selecting something that would be suitable for riding in the countryside and not be in complete agony?

There's a [list here](https://fatlama.com/london-rentals/bike-hire) i'm looking to rent from (as i have money off)

Any help would be appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: Would you kindly answer the following questions? You may edit your question for that purpose. How far and how long would you like to bike on that weekend? What is the terrain like? Flat, hilly, mountains? What type of roads are there, tarmac, gravel, rough trails?  One more thing, it appears the link does not work.

Comment: ps.: I am sorry for the rude down-vote you received by someone minutes after your first question. That was rude and trollish. If you have a moment, it would be good though if you read the beginners tour: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: do you know what sort of terrain you will be riding (asphalt or gravel trails)?

Comment: As a comment, I would talk to the rental agent. They are likely familiar with the terrain you are intending to ride. They will also be familiar with the suitable rentals they have available. You'll likely not enjoy riding a bike incompatible with your ability or the terrain.

Comment: The best bike is the one that fits you and feels comfortable.  Try a couple at the rental shop before settling.

Answer (score 2):

Quite a few different bikes there, but seeing as it is based in london, i assume you will be using the bike in mostly urban and city landscapes. My personal opinion would be to go with one of the many "Hybrid" bikes listed. Like one of the flat bar road bikes. If you go full road bike, you will be in "attack" position the entire tire and i imagine you would be more comfortable in an upright position where you can take in the scenery as well.

One thing to look into is what sort of insurance or theft policies are there? Parts of London could be a sketchy place to leave a bike so i would be sure you know the rules and liabilities involved with renting someone's bike. Also would be smart to inquire about repair services or rules if you were to get a flat or other issues.

Next, as others have mentioned, match whatever bike you choose with the type and length of riding you intend to do. A cruiser may be super comfortable for short jaunts around the block, but if you plan to put a lot of miles in, the comfort will loose it's bonus to expending extra effort.

Also, i would avoid an older model being new to bikes. You will likely want a full range of gears and easy to use simple components like trigger shifters.